# Sum of two nonnegative sequences converges to a limit implies that each sequence converges?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

More precisely:

Suppose that $a_n$ and $b_n$ are *nonnegative* sequences such that

\begin{equation}
a_n + b_n \rightarrow L> 0,\quad as\quad n\rightarrow\infty 
\end{equation}

What can we say about $a_n$ and $b_n$, in terms of their limit points?

As explained in the comments below, in general, both sequences may be divergent.

But what if we impose more conditions on them? For instance, what if $b_n$ (say) is *strictly positive*, or even *uniformly bounded from below*?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$a_{n}=1$ for even $n$, $a_{n}=0$ for odd $n$, $b_{n}=0$ for even $n$, $b_{n}=1$ for odd $n$, then $a_{n}+b_{n}=1$.

Comment: Thanks! However, this does imply that both sequences are bounded; thus each has at least one convergent subsequence... right?

Comment: Yes, true, you are right.